# Fetching the result from Scala Array based on a condition

Tags: arrays, scala

I have the below array with me -

```
 var  arrayInt: Array[Int] = Array(400, 200, 20, 30, 50,1000)
```

Also the below condition. I need to fetch the first 2 occurrences from the array where it satisfies the condition  arrayInt < int_max.

```
 var int_max = 100
```

Expected Output

```
Array( 20, 30)
```

Comment: In such case, first avoid using `Array` or `var`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What should be the best practice then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `filter` method available for all scala collections.

```scala
val arrayInt: Array[Int] = Array(400, 200, 20, 30, 50, 1000)
val filtered = arrayInt.filter(_ < 100).take(2)
println(filtered.mkString(","))
```

Answer (score 2):

Filtering the array on the condition removes the too-large numbers, then taking the first two of the remaining numbers like so:

```
val  arrayInt: Array[Int] = Array(400, 200, 20, 30, 50,1000)
val intMax = 100

arrayInt.filter( _ < intMax ).take( 2 )
```